# Determine $x \in A \implies x \in B$ using truth tables

Tags: real-analysis

I was just wondering about how to approach this question. If I have a universal set $U=\{1,2,3,4,5\}$ and sets $A=\{1,2\}, B=\{1,2,3\}$, I know that $x$ is in both set $A$ and set $B$ and hence $A$ is a subset of $B$.

However I'm confused about how can I write up a truth table to prove this? Do I simply write the universal set in the first column, all set to true values, followed by putting true values for Set $A$ in the next column for $\{1,2\}$ and false values for $\{3,4,5\}$ and do the same in the third column for Set $B$, true for $\{1,2,3\}$ and false for $\{4,5\}$ in order to create the compound statement $x \in A \implies x \in B$?

Or am I approaching this question differently than I should be?

Cheers for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Outline:

For the truth table, you take the statement x∈A⇒x∈B .... Now, under the two 'element of' signs you will have the 4 possible truth values. And under the implies sign, you should get all Ts which will prove it.